# how many solutions does a square root of a positive number have?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

So a friend of mine asked me how many solutions does $\sqrt{49}$, have. I replied with $\pm7$ since I remember when I was younger I didn't get full pot on my test cause I forgot to add the $\pm$ to the answer. But today I got told and learned something, that *by definition the square root of a positive integer is always positive*. So is it wrong that the answer is $\pm7$, my friend also told me that it's wrong cause I cannot get $-7$ from $\sqrt49$. I tried and I came up with two possible ways (I don't know if these are correct or not)

$\sqrt{49} \longleftrightarrow\sqrt{-7}\sqrt{-7}=\sqrt7\sqrt7\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{49}i^2=-7$

the other method I used was

$\sqrt49 \longleftrightarrow\sqrt{-7}\sqrt{-7}=(-7)^{1/2}(-7)^{1/2}=(-7)^{1/2+1/2}=(-7)^1=-7$

I know that $x^2=49$ has two possible answers.

Comment: keep in mind that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, that why there are two roots for such equation, but we only take positive value as arithmetic square root.

Comment: $\sqrt{49}$ is, by definition, the positive root of 49.

Comment: Nitpick:  $\sqrt {49}$ doesn't have any solutions because $\sqrt{49}$ is not a question.  That's like asking how many solutions does Spiderman have.  The $\sqrt{49} = 7$ and $7$ is ... a value.  Not a a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two numbers that you can square to get 49. You've correctly identified both.

What mathematicians normally mean when they write $\sqrt{x}$ is the positive number that, when squared, gives x. However, this definition breaks down every once in a while and is very context heavy.

I don't think such a distinction is worth argument, as long as you understand what someone else means with their terminology.

Comment: To nitpick.  The friend is wrong too.  $\sqrt{49}$ is a number.  Numbers do not have "solutions" because numbers are not questions.  That's like asking "How many solutions does 7 have".  The answer is "that question makes no sense; 7 is a number; 7 is 7 and that's all there is to it."

Comment: Indeed that is a nitpick.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{x}$ for real $x$ is defined to be the **positive** real solution of the equation $z^2 - x = 0$.

However, the question your friend asked is ill-formed, because asking "how many solutions $\sqrt{47}$ has" is not a proper question. There is no equation to solve, thus there are no solutions to speak of.

Answer (score 0):

Square root of positive real numbers are defined to take the **positive** root.  It is from definition but not from calculation.

$x^2=49$ does have $2$ roots, but we will only take the positive one for square root.

It is done, to preserve the property that $sqrt$ as a function, instead of a multi-valued mapping.

Comment: so saying that $\sqrt49=\pm7$ is wrong?

Comment: @user8700908 Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day when I was teaching in high school I remember a student who had just arrived from a foreign country (can't remember which country) telling me that where he was from, they used to write things like $$\sqrt{4}=\{-2, 2\}$$

which *does* make sense, in a way. So you are not plainly wrong. But this is not how you define a function in the classic, western sense. A *function* can take only one value at a time. If there are several choices that would seem natural, you have to choose one of them, once and for all, if you are to define a function.

Note however that there is a western notation that will output things like $\{-2, 2\}$. If you let $f(x)=x^2$ denote the square map, then we use the notation $f^{-1}(49)$ to denote the set of all inputs that will output $49$ via the function $f$. Therefore $$f^{-1}(49)=\{-7, 7\}$$

Comment: " But this is not how you define a function in the classic, western sense."  This is assume we are defining $\sqrt{}$ to be a function.  Which is the western way of doing it.  However we don't need to define $\sqrt{}$ as a function (I prefer to think of it as an *operation* not a function; but technically there is no difference), and we could think of it as a "solution set".  That is not incorrect but different.  However IMO I think the cost of not being able to refer to $\sqrt{49}$ as a specific value is too high.

Comment: What you think of is really a function. What would an "operation" have that a function doesn't (or the other way around)? A function doesn't have to be continuous or anything. It just needs a single, well-defined output for each input.

Comment: I said there is no technical difference between an operation and a function but I think most students will balk when first hearing that addition is a function.  Meanwhile functions/operations are themselves a subset of relations which don't require single output.  It is "western" to define it as a function whereas a relation/solution set is a valid alternative definition.  However we can not consider $\sqrt {49} $ as a *number* if we are to interpret it as a solution set.

Answer (score 0):

1) $\sqrt {49}$ is not a question and does not have any solutions.

2)"How many square roots does 49 have?" is a question and the answer is "2; 7 and -7".

3) "What are the square roots of 49" is another question and the answer to that is "7 and -7".

4)  And finally a fourth question is "What is the positive square root of 49" and the answer to that is "7".

Notice all four of those are *different* (non)questions!  And different questions have different answers.

So the answer to the question:

"What is $\sqrt 49$" is "By definition the positive square root of 49" is "$7$ or $-7$.

And so the *one* solution to $x = \sqrt{49}$ is just like the solution to $x = 3+4$.  It's $x = 7$.  That's it.

But the answer to the *different* question:

"What numbers when squared give you $49$" is "The square roots of $49$" is "There are two of them $7$ and $-7$".

ANd the solution to $x^2 = 49$ is:

$x^2 = 49 \iff x^2 - 49 = 0 \iff (x-7)(x+7) = 0 \iff x -7 =0$ OR $x+7 = 0 \iff x = 7$ OR $x = -7$.  So $x = \pm 7$.

Or to do it more quickly:

$x^2 = 49$

$x = \pm\sqrt {49}$

$x = \pm 7$.

====

The upshot is:

1) Every positive real number has two square roots; a positive value and a negative value, and the absolute value of these two roots are equal (i.e. the are equal in magnitude but of opposite parity.)

2) The notation $\sqrt {foo}$ is by definition the *positive* square root.  And so the notation $-\sqrt{foo}$ is by construction the *negative* square root.

So for $k > 0$ the *two* solutions to $x^2 = k$ are $x =\pm \sqrt k$ where $-\sqrt{k} < 0 < \sqrt{k}$.

Comment: Is this incorrect aswell?  $\sqrt{49} \longleftrightarrow\sqrt{-7}\sqrt{-7}=\sqrt7\sqrt7\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{49}i^2=-7$ 

the other method I used was

$\sqrt49 \longleftrightarrow\sqrt{-7}\sqrt{-7}=(-7)^{1/2}(-7)^{1/2}=(-7)^{1/2+1/2}=(-7)^1=-7$

Comment: That's not "incorrect"  so much as, to be meaningful, we must make our definitions consistant. $1=\sqrt {(-1)^2}\sqrt {(-1)}^2=-1$, obviously has some mistake but what?  It depends on how we define things.  If $\sqrt {x} $ for $x>0$ is defined to be the positive square root of x.  And if $\sqrt {-x} $ is defined to be $i\sqrt {x} $ (the other square root is $-i\sqrt {x} $), then it is not true that $\sqrt {xy}=\sqrt  x\sqrt y $.  But it is all a matter of definition.